# SQL Query to Retrieve Monthly Data

Tags: sql, redash

I'm working with the following SQL Query in Redash, the query retrieves monthly data from table.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table 
WHERE
"Date" between '2021-04-01T00:00:00.669976+00:00' and '2021-04-30T23:59:59.669976+00:00'
```

I'd like to know if there's a workaround to updating the `WHERE` clause in an efficient manner rather than manually typing it out at the end of each month.

Comment: use a date dimension.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  Redash is not a database; it is an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked well for me:

```
WHERE
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM  "Date") = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  "Date") = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I suggest you avoid any solution that involves doing a `convert` or other type of conversion with the `GRP_Date` field. By doing that, you do not allow SQL Server to be able to use an index if there is one for the `GRP_Date` field and this can affect your performance in a very obvious way.

And of course `between` is not ideal in this specific case for the reasons already mentioned in your question.

I suggest the following condition for the best performance (good use of the indexes) and to avoid problems with the hours

```
where GRP.GRP_date >= @since
and GRP.GRP_date < dateadd(day, 1, @until) -- @until + 1 day
```

In the case where:

- @since = 2016-11-01
- @until = 2016-11-14

```
where GRP.GRP_Fecha >= '2016-11-01'
and GRP.GRP_Fecha < '2016-11-15'
```

When ordering dates before `2016-11-15`, this includes all dates from `2016-11-14` regardless of time.

Comment: The answer is vague I'm unable to interpret or implement it